# Orientdb(2.1.8) Intersect function is not working

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, orientdb

I am qorking on OrientDB(2.1.8) database and executing the below query with OrientDB functions (unionall & intersection).

There are userunits of various users, So i want to display the results if atleast one userUnits of two users(@rid=#16:2131,@rid=#16:2130) intersect then result should be displayed.

Suppose user #16:2131 userUnits are [admin,manager]
and user #16:2131 userUnits are [admin] only

so 'admin' userUnits are common so results should be displayed
but Intersect command is not working.

my below query is working fine with "unionall" function but not working with "intersect".

```
SELECT expand(unionall($a, $b))
LET $a = (SELECT userUnits FROM #16:2131),
$b = (SELECT userUnits FROM #16:2130)
```

output comes-->
admin,manager
supervisor

But when i run my query with intersect function then neither it is showing me any error nor the display results.

```
SELECT expand(intersect($a, $b))
LET $a = (SELECT userUnits FROM #16:2131),
$b = (SELECT userUnits FROM #16:2130)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT intersect($a.userUnits, $b.userUnits)
LET $a = (SELECT userUnits FROM #16:2131),
$b = (SELECT userUnits FROM #16:2130)
```

I hope it helps

Bye

Comment: I Tried but same as earlier "unionall" is working but "intersect" is not working. my output is coming a blank array [].

Comment: Mmm, very strange: what is the type of field "userUnits" in your query?

Comment: "string" datatype. 
Is there any other way by which i can get the same results as i am trying to get using intersect functions?

Comment: I also Tried below these two queries also but getting the same results(blank). 
Neither getting any error nor the result
first query-->

`select userUnits from #16:2130 where userUnits CONTAINS (SELECT userUnits from #16:2131)`

second query-->

`select * from #16:2130 where userUnits in (SELECT userUnits from #16:2131)`

Comment: But which values @rid=#16:2130 contains? And which @rid=#16:2131? Because if @rid=#16:2130 contains ["admin"] and @rid=#16:2131 contains ["admin","manager"] your second query is correct: in fact, I've tried my case and I have ["admin"] as result.

Comment: I am having the same scenarios
@rid=#16:2130 contains ["admin"] and @rid=#16:2131 contains ["admin","manager"] 
so i run the second query but not getting the data

`select * from #16:2130 where userUnits in (SELECT userUnits from #16:2131)`
 
 **may I ask you which OrientDB version you are using because this issue is coming for all the version later on 2.0**
 
 I am using OrientDB 2.1.8.

Comment: I'm using your version (2.1.8) and my field "userUnits" is an embeddedlist type: and your? which type?

Comment: My field "userUnits" is a **String** type:

Comment: The function "intersect" runs with fileds of type "embeddedlist" not String.

Comment: ok can you help me to convert string datatype field i.e "userUnits" to EMBEDDEDLIST so that i can try my query again. I tried by changing in schema but getting an error message **the EMBEDDEDLIST does not support converting values** so do we need to change it at the time of importing the data(from the starting).

Comment: Ok, you can write `insert into "your_vertex_name" (userUnits) values (["admin","manager"])` for example...

Comment: It is working now thanks a lot
whole issue was due to the datatype.

Comment: Great: could you select my answer as best, please? Thanks again